# Remove blank page on Google Docs

Tags: google-docs

I have a simple 2-column table resume Google Document. For some reason, there is a blank page below it.

- If I click on the empty page and press Backspace nothing changes.
- I enabled the border of the table to check for spacing issues.

Here is a copy of the document with lipsium text that can be modified by anyone: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1l-kvEZ2WXh6-rCBgB0XRp93zDAOo07a5HF-H2OuF3KU/edit

Whats the problem here?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**The length of your text in the second column *(too long)* in combination with the column width**, causes the issue.

This is your doc now.

[image]

**Try removing some text** *(adsaadsaadsaaddsasdasad)* and the second page will go away.

This is with text reduced.

[image: less text]

OR

Try `Distribute columns` to see the *"real length"* of your cells.

[image: auto distribute columns]

and **manually adjust the width to optimize**.

[image: manually adjusted width]

Comment: Thats right, but it makes no sense that there is a new blank page, right?

Comment: Actually it does. The table is auto-expanding by column. You will get the same result if either of the columns *(actually cells)* is longer than the other. Give it a try with the first column as well.

Comment: Please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it and even [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well.

Comment: I upvoted, but I still look for another solution. Its correct that the last line increases the height (its not the length of the last line that causes the issue btw) - but as one can see on the borders, the table still fits on page one.

Comment: It is not just the last line, but the length but the amount of the text in the whole cell combined with the column width. Hold on. I will explain in details in my answer.

Comment: Please check the edited answer.

Comment: I think its just about the number of lines. Please see the updated document where every line in the second column is only 1 character long. The blank page appears depending on the number of lines in the right column. Manually adjusting the size of the left column does not help.

Comment: *"I think its just about the number of lines."*. As said, *"The length of your text in the second column (too long) in combination with the column width"*. Check it now. All I did was move the middle "divider". Now the lines in column 1 are too many, thus we have 3 pages. It is about the optimum combination.